# How do I display brackets around assumptions in Isabelle/jEdit?

Tags: jedit, isabelle, proof-general

When goals are displayed by Isabelle in ProofGeneral, assumptions are rendered as having brackets around them as so:

[image: ProofGeneral rendering of assumptions]

In Isabelle/jEdit, however, this seems to have changed to meta-implication arrows:

[image: jEdit rendering of assumptions]

While I understand the former is somewhat non-standard, I find it much easier to read. Is there a way to modify the behaviour of Isabelle/jEdit to print out goals in the old ProofGeneral style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format Isabelle renders its output is determined by Isabelle's "print modes". In ProofGeneral, the default `print_mode` includes the `brackets` mode, which renders brackets around assumptions, while the default jEdit `print_mode` includes `no_brackets`, which does the opposite.

The print mode can be changed either by setting `Plugins > Plugin Options > Isabelle/General > Print Mode` to `brackets` and restarting jEdit, by adding `-m brackets` to the `isabelle jedit` command line, or by including in your `~/.isabelle/etc/settings` file:

```
ISABELLE_JEDIT_OPTIONS="-m brackets"
```

This will result in jEdit displaying brackets like ProofGeneral:

[image: jEdit rendering brackets]

Comment: this path does not exist in my jedit `Plugins > Plugin Options > Isabelle/General > Print Mode`, can you update your answer please?

Comment: this path does not exist either `~/.isabelle/etc/settings`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into `Plugins -> Plugin Options -> Isabelle -> General`
2. then type in `brackets` in the Print Mode field.
3. Click Apply.
4. Then close out of Isabelle and restart it.

You should have brackets around your hypotheses thereafter.